# how can I transfer returned unknown type objects from CollectionView to MyObject

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I have created Collection view and I need to select multiple items. From what I found out from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/userinterface-collectionviewdemos/ it seems that once we need to select more items the observable collection must be object not MyClass

```
private readonly BindableProperty _diagnosticEventProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
        propertyName: nameof(Logs),
        returnType: typeof(ObservableCollection<LogEvent>),
        defaultValue: new ObservableCollection<LogEvent>(),
        declaringType: typeof(DiagnosticInfoViewModel));
    


public ObservableCollection<LogEvent> Logs
    {
        get => (ObservableCollection<LogEvent>) GetValue(_diagnosticEventProperty);
        set => SetValue(_diagnosticEventProperty, value);
    }
private List<LogEvent> _selectedEvent = new List<LogEvent>();
private ObservableCollection<object> _selectedEvents = new ObservableCollection<object>();
        public ObservableCollection<object> SelectedEvents
        {
            get => _selectedEvents;
            set
            {
                if (value != null && _selectedEvents != value)
                {
                    _selectedEvents = value;
                }
            }
        }
        
        public ICommand SelectionChangedCommand => 
            new Command<object>((obj) =>
            {
                Acr.UserDialogs.UserDialogs.Instance.Alert("You selected ");
            
                _selectedEvents.Add(obj);
                Test();
                
            });

private void Test()
        {
            var test = _selectedEvents.Count;
            foreach (object[] item in _selectedEvents)
            {
                
            }
        }

<CollectionView HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"  SelectionChangedCommandParameter="{Binding .}"
                    SelectionMode="Multiple"  SelectedItems="{Binding SelectedEvents}"
                    SelectionChangedCommand="{Binding SelectionChangedCommand}"
                    VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
                    ItemsSource="{Binding Logs, Mode=TwoWay}">
            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <templates:DiagnosticEventPageTemplate />
                </DataTemplate>
            </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
    </CollectionView>
```

This works fine, the command gets fired and I can see the items there, however I need to use these items as MyClass.

So ideally I shout I would do something like this

```
private void Test()
        {
            var test = _selectedEvents.Count;
            foreach (object item in _selectedEvents)
            {
                Level = item.Level,
                Text = item.Text
            }


        //Have also tried this, but that is still giving me object , so I still can't access the properties

var test = myObject.GetType();
            Console.WriteLine(test);
            var t = test.GetProperties();
            Type myType = myObject.GetType();
            
            IList<PropertyInfo> props = new List<PropertyInfo>(myType.GetProperties());

            foreach (PropertyInfo prop in props)
            {
                object propValue = prop.GetValue(myObject, null);

                Console.WriteLine(propValue);
            
                



                // Do something with propValue
            }
        }
```

please can you help how can I again transfer them to my custom object because the returned object don't have the properties I need? I have tried to search but this is such weird question that I get only post how to create an object

Comment: @Cfun thank you for the edit. Does my question make sense ? perprahs do you know the answer?

Comment: Do you know what class it is? Can you cast it to that class? Or do you need this to work for any class that happens to be in the list? I can't tell if you are storing MyClass objects or lists of LogEvents.

Comment: It would be helpful to me if you could show your ideal code. That is, what it would look like if you didn't have object confusing things. Then I'd have a better shot at giving you an answer that is closer to what you need.

Comment: "From what I found out from <link> it seems that once we need to select more items the observable collection must be object not MyClass"  Can you give me a deeper link? I don't see where it says that.

Comment: https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/blob/master/UserInterface/CollectionViewDemos/CollectionViewDemos/ViewModels/MonkeysViewModel.cs here its specified in the example and here http://lpains.net/articles/2020/xamarin-forms-collection-view-selected-items/

Comment: I have tied to add my own class however really nothing happened

Comment: sorry for late reply its 7 am here :) @BWhite

Answer (score 0):

you just need to cast them to the correct type

```
List<LogEvent> selectedLogEvents = new List<LogEvent>();

foreach (object item in _selectedEvents)
{
   selectedLogEvents.Add((LogEvent)item);
}
```

Comment: sorry but like this I get an exception System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.
  at DiagnosticInfoViewModel.Test (System.Object myObject) [0x0004a] in /view/viewmodel/DiagnosticInfoViewModel.cs:72

Comment: I have tried to make selectedLogEvents Observable collection but no help

Comment: What is the type of Logs?

Comment: ObservableCollection

Comment: what it is it a collection of?  `ObservableCollection<T>`, what is the type of `T`?

Comment: I was able to easily cast the SelectedItems to the correct type in the Xamarin sample you linked to.  What does the debugger tell you the  **actual** type is of the object you're trying to cast?